# Defining The Centre Of Electric Field Induced Due To Time Varying Magnetic Field

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

I was studying electric field induced due to time varying magnetic field and i read that **concentric circular lines of non-conservative electric field is induced due to time varying magnetic field into the plane.** (Considering this case as an example)

But however i also learned that the centers of the concentric circles of electric field cannot be known for certain.

So my question is , is there a way to define the center of the circular electric field that is induced? About which point would i draw/plot the circular field?
Thanks.